# NSString is realeased before time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm using `WKWebView` in my app to get data from The HTML with javascript, I'm using this code:

```
NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxxx('%@');",html];

__block NSString *searchJson = nil;

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.searchWebView evaluateJavaScript:jsCall completionHandler:^(id result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error || result == nil || ![result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            searchJson = nil;
        } else {
            searchJson = result;
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
});
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

if ([NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:searchJson]) {
    return nil;
}

return [self getResultsWithJSonString:searchJson];
```

I need to wait for the response so i'm using the `semaphore_wait` method, It's working fine but sometimes the `searchJson` is released from memory and in the `[NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:searchJson]` I'm getting this error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000443439e70
```

Any idea of how to fix this released problem? I'm using Non-ARC in my project.

Comment: maybe try `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` just inside the bottom of the `dispatch_sync` or use `dispatch_async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is non-ARC, the you must retain result explicitly (because callback might be in different thread), like

```
} else {
    searchJson = [result retain];
}
```

and then, to avoid leak, use

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
[searchJson autorelease]; // << call it here, once !!

if ([NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:searchJson]) {
    return nil;
}

return [self getResultsWithJSonString:searchJson];
```

Comment: I'm using `searchJson` also in another method, so when I finish using it I should call `[searchJson autorelease]`?

Comment: @MTA, what do you mean by *in another* method? The rule is to keep retain/autorelease pair, as shown; if you call second autorelease you'll got crash at the end of autorelease pool. It would be better if you show code.